# What is the order of evaluation of function arguments java

Tags: java, function, oop, constructor, parameter-passing

So I have created a class that allows you to optionally pass in a new instance of itself:

```
public ExampleObject(String name, ExampleObject... exampleObjects) {

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   ExampleFunction(new ExampleObject("Test", new ExampleObject("Test2")));
}
```

How would this execute? Would the constructor for the outer ExampleObject be called first, or the inner?

Comment: You could test this by printing out the `name` from within the constructor. It has to be the "inner" constructor first though. Think about it, how would the "outer" constructor be invoked with the needed arguments if those arguments have not been evaluated yet.

Comment: always starts from inside, so in this case test2 --> test --> exampleFunction

Comment: The inner constructor. How should the outer be called without knowing the result of the inner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evaluation of arguments is described by [JLS 15.12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2).

An excerpt:

> The argument expressions, if any, are evaluated in order, from left to
>   right. If the evaluation of any argument expression completes
>   abruptly, then no part of any argument expression to its right appears
>   to have been evaluated, and the method invocation completes abruptly
>   for the same reason. The result of evaluating the j'th argument
>   expression is the j'th argument value, for 1 ≤ j ≤ n.

Applying this to your case the evaluation order is:

```
ExampleFunction(new ExampleObject("Test", new ExampleObject("Test2")));
- new ExampleObject("Test", new ExampleObject("Test2"))
- - "Test"
- - new ExampleObject("Test2")
- - - "Test2"
```

This is the order in which the arguments are called for evaluation. This means in turn that to evaluate `new ExampleObject("Test", new ExampleObject("Test2"))` first `new ExampleObject("Test2")` will be evaluated.

Answer (score 5):

Before function call all its parameters must be evaluated. So `new ExampleObject("Test2")` will be called first, then `new ExampleObject("Test", <object created on first step>)`

Answer (score 0):

Since Test ExampleObject requires ExampleObject object, which here in this case Test2 ExampleObject, so Test2 ExampleObject will be created first followed by Test ExampleObject followed by ExampleFunction.
So order is from inner to outer.